# Grouping by only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I would like to group by the ID, how could I do it?

Thank you!

EDIT:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOOU0.png)

```
SELECT ID AS 'Case Number',
       CASE WHEN Group LIKE '%1st%' THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2))  END AS '1st - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       CASE WHEN Group LIKE '%2nd%' THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) END AS '2nd - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       CASE WHEN (Group NOT LIKE '%1st%' AND Group NOT LIKE '%2nd%')  THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) END AS '3rd - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',xy_duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) AS 'Processing Time (Business Days)',
       CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',pause_duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) AS 'Freeze Time (Business Days)' 
  FROM MainTable WITH (nolock)
 WHERE active = 'false'
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, your question is not clear/

Comment: Are there any more than one xy_duration, pause_durations, durations, or groups per id?

Comment: Do you really *need* to use `NOLOCK`? Do you understand what it does,  and (more importantly) the problems it can cause, right?

Comment: Hi, 

Added the example as a picture.

Comment: you'd better sharing the example data as text rather than image. This way, helping people might easily manipulate the data, besides some people behind firewalls may not see the images.

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, 

Thank you for the advice, in the future I'll do that in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need conditional aggregation which includes `SUM()` function :

```
SELECT ID AS 'Case Number',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Group LIKE '%1st%' THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) END) AS '1st - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Group LIKE '%2nd%' THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) END) AS '2nd - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (Group NOT LIKE '%1st%' AND Group NOT LIKE '%2nd%')  THEN CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2)) END) AS '3rd - Elapsed time (Business Days)',
       SUM(CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',xy_duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2))) AS 'Processing Time (Business Days)',
       SUM(CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000',pause_duration) AS decimal)/28800 AS decimal (8,2))) AS 'Freeze Time (Business Days)' 
  FROM MainTable with (nolock)
 WHERE active = 'false'
 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!